# Why echo with option -e behave differently in command line vs within sh script?

Tags: bash, echo

Using LinuxMint 17.2, kernel 4.4.0-97-generic. I made a tiny TestEcho.sh script which contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "\e[1;31m Text in Color \e[0m\n"
for code in {33..43}; do echo -e "\e[38;05;${code}m $code: Text in Color"; done ; echo "";
```

The `echo -e` command, when executed in the command line, gives the expected output. i.e it interprets the escape code and display the text in color.

The same command within a .sh script, `echo` seems to ignore the `-e` option and displays `-e` as literal text. Additionally, the for loop seems also to be broken. Is this caused by `echo -e`? And more importantly how to fix the script?

**ANSWER** (thanks George Vasiliou): Run script with `bash` instead of `sh`

```
$ bash ~/Download/TestEcho.sh
```

[image: echo -e in cmdline vs within sh script]

Comment: You're having your script interpreted by `sh`, not `bash`. See also [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803). Note that to be POSIX compliant `echo -e` has to output `-e<newline>` (and `echo -e '\e'` is unspecified as arguments contain backslashes).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The first line of the script is `#!/bin/bash` would that have the effect to tell the shell to interpret the script with bash?

Comment: @Polymerase Not if you explicitly say sh like you did in the screenshot.

Comment: Ok thanks gentlemen for the pointers. I'll read further to find the answer. Shell script is not my strength. I wonder what is wrong in the question but, the down votes seem to indicate it violates something.

Comment: Run your script using `$ bash ~/Downloads/Testecho.sh` instead of `$ sh`.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou Oh that's it. Thanks, can you answer in a separate post so I can mark as answer?

Comment: This is what other fellows tried to explain to you... When you use `$sh` to run your script you are calling `sh` which is NOT bash.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou OK that clears all the confusions. I'll read about shell when I'll have some free time. I thought `sh` is the way to invoke a shell which happens to be bash in my case. Sorry for all the novice mistakes. Thanks everybody

Answer (score 2):

bash and sh are different kind of shell. bash is the latest and smarter than sh. In your script, you write `#!/bin/bash` that means it will run using `bash` shell. But if you use `sh ~/Download/TestEcho.sh` then it will run using `sh` shell.

Comment: Yes, but bash in this respect is *broken*; it doesn't correctly honor the POSIX sh standard, which specifies that `echo -e` **must** print `-e` on output. (bash's authors are aware of this, which is why enabling both the `xpg_echo` and `posix` options simultaneously will make `echo -e` in bash print `-e` on output, so it isn't something you can safely rely on unless you know the active runtime options in use!)

Comment: ...incidentally, `echo` being poorly specified and implemented in different ways by different shells is also something the authors of the POSIX specification are aware of, which is why the APPLICATION USAGE section of the [POSIX specification for `echo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) recommends using `printf` instead.